# c# sort HTTP request headers

Tags: c#, http-headers, httpwebrequest, webrequest, request-headers

I have an issue with a request to a website

when I go by the browser, all request go success,

but when I go by

```
(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
this.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"); 
etc...
```

a have error 502,

when I compare the 2 request, I found the difference is in the "order" of the header request,

when I send the headers in this order the request success,

> Host: www.WebSite.com
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
>
> Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
>
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8"

but in this order what is generated by

```
(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
```

i heve error 502

> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
>
> Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
>
> Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
>
> Host: www.WebSite.com
>
> Connection: Keep-Alive"

what is the way to control the sort of the headers?

thanks

Comment: I really never heard of a standard http server depending on the order of http headers. What server engine is running on the host? Some standard product (e.g iis, apache, nginx,...) or some self coded service. I see one difference in the accepted encodings. The browser request accepts also brotlin (br) compression. Your request doesn't. Maybe some gateway (502 is bad gateway) needs brotlin compression?

Comment: the issue is same when is "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br",    the problem is the only the order of the headers

Comment: i can send u in private the address , and then u can see in fiddler the problem....